# How to use paypal Sandbox webhooks on local setup?

Tags: webhooks

I am playing around with Paypal REST(php) enviroment and i like to play around with the sandbox webhooks. 
Is it possible to use paypal sandbox webhooks with a local setup? `http://localhost/test`

is a invalid url

any suggestions?

Comment: We have a free tool for this: https://www.runscope.com/docs/passageway

Answer (score 8):

As @zeyu says, you can't do it directly. Another service that you can use to achieve this is https://ngrok.com/. Hope it's useful for someone!

It will give you a link something like this: `http://75z929f4.ngrok.io`, which I set to a development ENV variable of `APP_HOST`.

And popped into the webhook as such:

```
  def generate_url
    values = {
      business: ENV["PAYPAL_ACCOUNT"],
      cmd: '_xclick',
      return: ENV["APP_HOST"] + @return_path,
      custom: @user.id,
      upload: 1,
      invoice: Time.now,
      currency_code: 'GBP',
      amount: @price,
      no_shipping: 1,
      item_name: self.purchase_name,
      item_number: @product_id,
      quantity: 1,
      notify_url: ENV["APP_HOST"] + @notify_path,
      on0: ('Coupon Code' if @coupon_code.present?),
      os0: @coupon_code
    }

    "#{ENV["PAYPAL_URL"]}/cgi-bin/websr?" + values.to_query
  end
```

Final note, you'll need to update the `APP_HOST` every time you re-run ngrok as you'll get a new identifier from them. That'll link everything up so you can send this request from localhost and have the response return successfully.

Answer (score 6):

no, it doesn't work in this way, cuz localhost is not a valid address for paypal webhook. 
however, you can try it with requestbin, [requestbin](http://requestb.in/) . remember using https instead of http while setting the webhook url up.

Answer (score 6):

### The simplest: receive webhook online

https://webhook.site/ is a single page, simple, no login. It will receive webhooks in real time and display all details about the received payload (body, headers...)

[image: webhook.site image]

---

### Second method: forward webhooks to localhost

With just a bit more setup you can forward received webhooks with a free service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to a `localhost` address. You need to login for security concerns.
On one cli command, it will then put online any `localhost` address (should be used for development only).

Comment: So much easier to setup and use! Thanks for sharing